# Request Type of Cron

Tags: php, cron

I want to know the Request Type of Cron. like CURL, sends HTTp Request to the server.
then what type of Request Cron Sends to SERVER?

Any Help?

Comment: cron does not send HTTP requests. If you use cron to trigger something which sends an HTTP request, it's up to you what it sends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron` sends no traffic of the TCP variety, it simply runs jobs at predefined intervals (nothing stops the jobs run by `cron` from doing so but that's totally separate to `cron` itself).

The only communications that `cron` itself does is if you start up something like `crontab` to edit the files used by `cron` - it will generally make the changes then send a signal (`SIGHUP` from memory) to the `cron` server to tell it to re-read the files. You cal also edit the files via a different method then send that signal to `cron` using, for example`, the`kill` command.

Comment: so it will not contain any header information?

Comment: @Hasina, no, it won't. Signals carry no extraneous information, just the fact that the signal was raised.

Comment: please check this url. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/cron
it says that cron sends HTTP request at 2nd Paragraph.

Comment: @Hasina What kind of cron job are you using?! The standard Linux `cron` is not the same as the Google App Engine "Scheduled Tasks".

Comment: @Hasina, that's a `cron` _job,_ not `cron` itself. A `cron` job (ie, a job run by `cron`) can pretty well do anything it wants to. As to your link, that's not `cron`, it's some sort of Google-supplied service, and it states _explicitly_ what it does, a HTTP GET request, so I'm not sure where your confusion lies.

Comment: ok. i got it. I am using Cron for my application and it process some functions in it. I just want to know about either it sending request to server ot not? and if it sending request then what type of Request is it?. Thanks for your answers.